# How to use the lambda in sorted?

Tags: python

```
sorted(arr, key=lambda x:(self.function(x), x))
```

What's the meaning of `(self.function(x), x)`?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what self is. In general see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html.

Answer (score 0):

This allows sorting by two criteria. If two values are equal for `self.function(x)`, they will be sorted by `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` parameter of the `sorted` method takes in a function reference that returns a key to be used for sorting purposes.

as an example

```py
arr = ["apple", "Andrew", "Cat", "cool"]
print(sorted(arr, key=lambda item: item.lower()))
```

would sort the items in the arr based on their `str.lower` representation.

the following snippet

```py
sorted(arr, key=lambda x:(self.function(x), x))
```

sorts the items in `arr` based on the tuple `(self.function(x), x)`,
see [this](https://pythonguides.com/python-sort-list-of-tuples/#:%7E:text=In%20python%2C%20to%20sort%20list,the%20elements%20in%20descending%20order.) post to see how python sorts an array of tuples.